# When to add more contracts to WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, oop, inheritance, reflection

I have a simple database application, and am using WCF and Entity Framework for my database interactions.

In my service, I have a parent class called DatabaseTable, and all other classes inherit from this class, and override the methods which are listed below (these are also in my Service Contract and exposed to my client side app)

Select
Update
Insert
Remove
GetAll
GetSetByKey

Each of these services accepts a DatabaseTable object as a parameter, and does what is needed.

The problem is, one of my classes, Part, has multiple ways to GetSetByKey(which fills a list based on criteria sent in the DataBaseObject paramater). The other classes all grab from the primary key, but this one, I need to GetSets(or lists) by different criteria, like Vendor, PurchaseOrderNumber, Claim, InvoiceNumber, ShipToUser, etc...

What I started doing was using if statements like below

```
if (this.Claim == 0) // Get By PO
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.InvoiceNumber) && this.VendorCode == 0)
    {
        parts = (from part in context.Parts where part.PurchaseOrder == this.PurchaseOrder select part).ToList<Parts>();
    }
    else if (this.VendorCode == 0)
    {
         parts = (from part in context.Parts where part.InvoiceNumber == this.InvoiceNumber select part).ToList<Parts>();

    }
    else
    {
          parts = (from part in context.Parts where part.VendorCode == this.VendorCode select part).ToList<Parts>();
    }
}
else
{
     parts = (from part in context.Parts where part.Claim == this.Claim select part).ToList<Parts>();
}
```

This worked good when I only had one other condition, but as you can see it is getting out of hand.  I am aware I could use Reflection, pass the name of the field, and use that to do the query, but I have been told Reflection is really expensive processor wise.

I am trying to keep my Service clean, so it only has basic SQL commands, instead of adding specific Contracts like `GetPartsByVedndor()` or `GetPartsByPurchaseOrder()`. I have no logical reason except it keeps the service implementation very clean.

Are there any other suggestions on how to do this better, because I am at a loss except for Reflection or adding new methods to the service.  If it seems OK to use Reflection here can you please explain when it is not OK.

Comment: Reflection sounds like it could be an injection risk. Not a show stopper, but something you'd need to watch out for. Also, if your contract doesn't define what fields can be searched against, how will a consumer know? `GetPartsByPurchaseOrder` makes it clear that parts can be retrieved by purchase order, but a generic `GetParts` does not. Just food for thought...

Comment: Thank you for the comment, the person knows what class they are running the operation against based on the DatabaseObject they send to the service.  Since it is a polymorphic relationship, if you request a Select operation with a Part object as argument, which is a descendant of a DatabaseObject, it is calling Select command in the Part class.

Comment: I think you've misinterpreted what I said. `Part` is essentially a *table*. What I'm talking about is a service contract that makes it clear what ways that table can be searched. You're concerned that multiple methods, like `GetPartsByVendor` and `GetPartsByPurchaseOrder` would be "messy", but its advantage is that it clearly shows what ways you can search for parts. An alternative implementation (say, based on reflection) may end up obscuring that information.

Comment: @Daryl I agree with Snixtor, clearly defined endpoints are easier to manage and **easier to consume** (in my opinion) than _clean_ one-size-fits-all interfaces.  Are you using generics on `DatabaseTable`?  If so, I assume it's `DatabaseTable<TDatabaseTable>`?  If you really insist on sticking with generics (assuming you're using them) you could consider `DatabaseTable<TSource> : DatabaseTable<TSource, TKey>`, and following that assumption change for example `GetSet<Parts>(new Foo() { Claim = 4 })` to `GetSet<Parts, Claim>(4)`, but it's a slippery slope.

Comment: @Snixtor - go ahead and post an answer, sound like I am trying to be clever instead of do the logical thing.